# How do i hide categories from menus which don't yet contain posts?

Tags: categories

I would like to hide a large number of categories from both the primary and secondary menus which have already been create however don't as yet contain posts.

Any PHP code i can use for this as there's a large number of categories.

Comment: What does the code that generates the menus look like?

Comment: Its  a child theme built on Genesis

Answer (score 0):

It depends which function you are using for querying those categories, but all of them has `hide_empty` argument

for example for:

```
<?php
     get_terms( $taxonomies, $args );
     $taxonomies = array( 
        'post_tag',
        'my_tax',
     );
     $args = array(
         'hide_empty'    => true, 
     ); 
?>
```

[get_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)

by default, hide_empty argument is empty so check if it's false in you code.

Comment: I just don't understand how to put this is a custom function

Comment: what is this plugin or whatever you are using for displaying those menus?

Comment: no plugin. Its the default Genesis menu which uses the WordPress menu.